# How do I properly write trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

Suppose I have this function template:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto DoSomething(const T1& arg);
```

Of course this function needs a trailing return type which, considering the function's purpose, I really could not get right.

What this function is supposed to do is to use `arg`, do some operation with `arg` and a `T2` object and use the result of that operation as the return value of the function. Clearly, `DoSomething()`'s return type must (compatibly) match with the return type of the operation done for `arg` and the `T2` object.

Suppose again that we make `DoSomething()` do some real operation, like multiplication. We would then write `DoSomething()` as like the code below:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto DoSomething(const T1& arg) -> /* trailing return-type */ {
    T2 t2Obj;   // Or have it obtained in some other way
    return arg * t2Obj;
}
```

**How should I then form the trailing return-type for this?**

---

P.S.: I've tried using `decltype(arg * T2)`, `decltype(T1 * T2)` and `decltype(T1::operator * (T2))` and some other really bizarre-looking `decltype`s for the trailing-return type. None of them worked.

Comment: Am I wrong, or should `-> decltype(arg * T2())` work?

Comment: I'm not overly sure if it's right. I found what seems to be the common way of explaining it without the suffix return (e.g., [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13100941/C%2B%2B11.pdf) and [here](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#suffix-return)), and that's `*(T2 *)(0)`. Perhaps that's to avoid the need for a default constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `decltype` and `std::declval<>` as:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto DoSomething(const T1& arg) -> decltype(arg * std::declval<T2>())
{
    T2 t2Obj;   // Or have it obtained in some other way
    return arg * t2Obj;
}
```

because `T2` might not have default constructor, so `decltype(arg *T2())` may not work.

But then I also notice that if `T2` doesn't have default constructor, then you would **not** be able to write `T2 t2Obj` either. So **if** you *require* `T2` to have default constructor, then you can simply write this:

```
-> decltype(arg *T2()) //requirement : T2 must have default constructor
```

that should also work **if you *require* `T2` to have default constructor!**

Comment: Sweet, that easily tops what I was going to post.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: See my answer, edited it with little explanation.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, The errors are spiteful, but adding a default constructor fixes everything: http://liveworkspace.org/code/XOkoh$9. Of course, now that I know about `std::declval`, I'd suggest it because it works for everything.

Comment: Of course, and @chris, thanks for the insight. Not so silly me after all.